# How to sort an output file in Linux based on a condition of the first value of that file?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, command-line, terminal

I have an output coming from a Perl script containing more than 500 numbers (positives and negatives). I want to make a sort based on the first value of that output.

For example:

```
-2 or 2
 3
-1
-5
```

If the first value is `2` then the output should be:

```
 3
 2
-1
-5
```

If the first value is `-2` then the output should be:

```
-5 
-2
-1
 3
```

I wrote

```
# if the first value is positive number then do a reverse sort, if negative do a normal sort.
script outpout| {if [[awk FNR == 1 && $1 -le 0]] then sort -k1nr else sort k1n  fi }
```

I got an `> (blinking space)` as an output. Is it any issue with my syntax (missing a symbol?) If you any idea how to do this kind of sort it using another way it will be welcome.

Comment: You can use [Shell Check](https://shellcheck.net) to help with syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
FIRST=`head -1 output`

if [ $FIRST -lt 0 ]
then
    #Negative
    sort -n output
elif [ $FIRST -gt 0 ]
then
    #Positive
    sort -nr output
else
    echo "Neither Positive Nor Negative"
fi
```